# SQL: Selecting all tuples which contain a certain value in a column after using count

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following table called Stores:

```
Name   |   Category   |   Industry 

ABC         appliances      retail 
XYZ         banking         finance 
NZE         clothing        retail
JKI         tutoring        education
```

I would like to output all the Names that are the only one in their Industry (e.g. XYZ and JKI are the only Names in their Industry).

I have the following query:

```
select s.Name, s.Industry, a.Number
from Stores s
inner join (
select Industry, count(*) as Number
from Stores group by Industry
) a
on s.Industry = a.Industry;
```

I get an output table which has an attribute called Number which gives the total number of times each Industry appears in the table Stores. How can I select all the tuples which have the value of 1 in the Number column after using the inner join?

Comment: adding a where at the end of the query?

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `where` condition

```
select s.Name, s.Industry, a.Number
from Stores s
inner join (
select Industry, count(*) as Number
from Stores group by Industry
) a
on s.Industry = a.Industry where a.Number=1
```

Answer (score 1):

use corelated subquery

```
select s.* from stores s
where exists ( select 1 from Stores s1 where s.Industry=s1.Industry
                               having count(*)=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT s.*
FROM Stores s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Stores s1 WHERE s1.Industry = s.Industry AND s1.Name <> s.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use aggregation:

```
select industry, max(name) as name
from stores
group by industry
having count(*) = 1;
```

If there is only one name, then `max(name)` is the one.

If `name`s can be repeated in the table, then:

```
having min(name) = max(name)
```